# Когда "напротив" разумно сопроводить тире? Где ему (тире) место?

Tags: пунктуация

> Отсутствие школьных занятий вовсе не означает безделья, напротив
>   повышает уровень ответственности родителей и даёт им возможность
>   разумно распоряжаться временем.

Какие ошибки в моей правке:

*Отсутствие школьных занятий вовсе не означает безделья, напротив -
повышает уровень ответственности родителей и даёт им возможность
разумно распоряжаться временем.*

Но с такой же легкостью я бы восприняла тире впереди:

*Отсутствие школьных занятий вовсе не означает безделья - напротив,
повышает уровень ответственности родителей и даёт им возможность
разумно распоряжаться временем.*

Если какое-нито чёткое правило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Отсутствие школьных занятий вовсе не означает безделья, **напротив –** повышает уровень ответственности родителей и даёт им возможность разумно распоряжаться временем.

(2) Отсутствие школьных занятий вовсе не означает безделья, **а, напротив**, повышает уровень ответственности родителей и даёт им возможность разумно распоряжаться временем.

Из справочника по пунктуации: Она была несколько мечтательна, но не старалась этого выказывать, **напротив** – стыдилась этого, как слабости. М. Лермонтов, Княгиня Лиговская.

Кто не хочет жениться, тот не сумасшедший, **а, напротив**, умнейший человек... (Чехов).